# Linking invitation data to review data via Trust Pilot API's

Tags: trustpilot

I'm currently pulling review data for all my business units, when the data shows the source "invite" I'd like to find an identifier that I can use to link back to the actual invitation that went out to the customer and thus have additional information on the customer. Is there any way to do this?

I referred to the review data returned from the business units API but see no reference to an invitation id linked to reviews where the source is invite, thus I cannot track back a review to an invite that was sent out.